# Symfony2 FlashBag stopped working after upgrade to 2.4?

Tags: session, symfony

In my controller I used this code to add a flash-message and redirect:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Foo Message');    
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('list_route'));
```

I displayed the messages in the template with this code:

```
<div id="flashes" class="row-fluid">
  {% for type, flashMessages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
    {% for flashMessage in flashMessages %}
      <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        {{ flashMessage|raw }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This worked perfectly until I upgraded from symfony 2.3 to 2.4.1.

There is no error, nothing wrong in my logs. The message is simply not displayed, `app.session.flashbag` is empty.

Did something change with the flashbag? How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `Liip\CacheControlBundle` by chance? I had the exact same problem and after some digging I found out that this bundle clears the flashbag.

in `config.yml` see if there is a `flash_message_listner: true` line and if there is turn it to `false` and things should work again.

I did this as an answer because I don't have enough rep to comment. I imagine that `Liip\CacheControlBundle` would have done that in the previous version too, but I thought I would give it a shot because it worked for me.

Instead of getting the standard distribution bundle I got the REST distribution and it came with this package which includes that `flash_message_listner: true` by default. Simply flipping that, fixed my problem.

Comment: Yes, I have added Liip\CacheControlBundle recently. You may be right. I'll test it tomorrow. Thanks :) PS. welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Comment: Thank you! And I am glad to help. I was wracking my brain for a solution to this and finally found it. I am glad I could help someone out with this! :D