# Symfony 2.4 app.session.flashbag.all() returns empty value

Tags: php, session, symfony, twig

I have a trouble with using the flashbag messages. My case is quite simple :

### My code

1. Editing a page using a form :

   ```
   # src/Namespace/MyBundle/Resources/views/Edit/form.html.twig
   <form action="{{ path('form_url_save', {'id': id }) }}" method="POST">
       {{ form_widget(form) }}
   </form>
   ```
2. Save the data form in a database via a controller :

   ```
   # src/Namespace/MyBundle/Controller/EntityController.php
   public function saveAction(Request $request, Entity $entity = null) {
       try {
           if (!$entity) {
               $entity = new Entity();
           }

           $form = $this->createForm(new EntityType(), $entity);

           if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
               $form->submit($request);

               if ($form->isValid()) {
                   // Entity manager
                   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                   // Persist data
                   $em->persist($form->getData());
                   // Saving process
                   $em->flush();
                   // Add flashbag message
                   $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'The backup was done successfully'));
               } else {
                   throw new \Exception($form->getErrorsAsString());
               }
           }
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $e->getMessage());
       }

       return $this->redirect('home_page_url');
   }
   ```
3. Display a successfull message on front :

   ```
   # app/Resources/views/front.html.twig
   <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
           <div class="main">
               {% set flashbag = app.session.flashbag.all %}
               {% if flashbag is not empty %}
                   <div class="messages-container">
                       {% for type, messages in flashbag %}
                           {% for message in messages %}
                               <div class="alert alert-{{ type }}">
                                   {{ message }}
                               </div>
                           {% endfor %}
                       {% endfor %}
                   </div>
               {% endif %}

               <div class="content">
                   // My content
               </div>
           </div>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

### How my theme is organized ?

```
app/Resources/views/front.html.twig
  |__ src/Namespace/MyBundle/Resources/views/Edit/form.html.twig // extends front.html.twig
```

### My trouble :

- `app.session.flashbag.all` in `front.html.twig`
  ==> Flashbag is empty
- `app.session.flashbag.all` in `form.html.twig`
  ==> Flashbag is good and had the success message

So why i can't put the code in the `front.html.twig` ?

Comment: You should do `app.session.getFlashBag().get('name_of_flash_bag')`
According to : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: I have already tested it but it doesn't work (same results)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just stumbled on the same problem and found this: [Symfony2 FlashBag stopped working after upgrade to 2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439025/symfony2-flashbag-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-2-4)

If the other subject doesn't answer your question you might want to try and dump your flashbag to see it's structure. Do do so, try adding this in your twig template:

```
{% set array = app.session.flashbag.all %}
{% dump(array) %}
```

You might be surprised by what comes out, at least I've been:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "Ceci est un test de flashbag" } }
```

Which means that you do have messages in your flashbag but you can't get the content the right way as it's in a second array. My solution:

```
{% for tag, line in array %}
  {% for underline in line %}
    <div class="{{tag}}">{{ underline }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: {% dump(array) %} should be replaced with {{ dump(array) }} owerwise you will get the error message "Unknown "dump" tag."

Answer (score 13):

This is because `FlashBag::all()` returns all messages and then empty the flashes container. Use `FlashBag::peekAll()` method to check if flashbag contains messages.

Example:

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.peekAll()|length %}
    {% include 'BraincraftedBootstrapBundle::flash.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```